# Why we need noinline in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, inline

I'm reading `kotlin` doc and can't understend one thing.

We can use `noinline` modifier to mark that lambda shouldn't be `inline`. But what is the real case when we really need it?

I understend what `noinline` does, but can't understand why.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Notice that when `inline` is added to a function/method declaration, *all* of its lambda parameters are inlined.

Also notice that there are some ways in which you can use a lambda parameter, that requires the lambda to be not inlined. For example, passing it to another, non-inlined function, or assigning it to a variable:

```
var func: (() -> Unit)? = null
inline fun foo(x: () -> Unit, y: () -> Unit) {
    notInlined(x) // x must be not inlined for this to work
    func = x // x must be not inlined for this to work
}
```

So what if I want to do `notInlined(x)`, but I still want to inline `y`? This is where I use `noinline`:

```
inline fun foo(noinline x: () -> Unit, y: () -> Unit)
```

IntelliJ even gives this as a suggestion:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One thing I notice is that this for example is allowed, but "end of runLambda" is never reached then.

```
fun main() {
    runLambda {
        println("lambda")
        return
    }

}

inline fun runLambda(lambda: ()->Unit) {
    lambda.invoke()
    println("end of runLambda")
}
```

if you want to ensure that the function completely runs until the end `noinline` could fix it because then it won't allow the `return`

[image]

Although `crossinline` can do the same and I think that one is actually meant for that. I'm not sure what the difference is